# How to expand \rightmark?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, latex3

I am puzzled why I cannot expand `\rightmark` to pass to another macro. Consider the following mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{item1,item2}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\lohead{%
    {%
        \exp_args:NNV \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_seq_sec_parts \rightmark%
        \seq_item:Nn \l_seq_sec_parts {1}%
    }}
\rohead{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

This code sets `\rightmark` to a comma separated list using `\sectionmark`. Then, while setting up a left odd page heading, the code tries to retrieve the first item of the list. First, it calls `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn` to convert the list into a sequence, then `\seq_item:Nn` returns the first item of the sequence.

`\exp_args:NNV` is supposed to fully expand `\rightmark` and pass the expansion as an argument to `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn`.

I expect to see `item1` in the heading. However, it doesn't happen. `item1,item2` is printed instead, which means `\rightmark` wasn't expanded. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I add `\cs_show:N \rightmark` to your `\lohead` code, I get

```
> \rightmark=macro:->\expandafter \@rightmark \firstmark \@empty \@empty .
```

With `\exp_args:NNV` you don't fully expand the third argument, but just get its first level expansion with a pair of braces around.

You need to expand `\rightmark` in order to arrive at the comma separated list, but not expanding “too much”, because fragile commands might break the construction.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{item1,item2}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { e }
\lohead
 {
  \clist_item:en { \text_expand:n { \rightmark } } { 1 }
 }
\rohead{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

However, this might break if fragile commands are used in the marks. For this you can u

Comment: This is great. Thank you for extending my knowledge.